# Filter Laravel Collection not works

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have this collection called $api_items. And I want remove all null values of this collection:

```
Collection {#365 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Article {#342 ▼
      +user_id: null
      +article_id: 1304
      +family_id: null
      +active: true
      +creation_date: null
      +name: "CUENTO "AMIGOS/AS PARA SIEMPRE" ESTANDAR"
      +description: null
      +detail: null
      +constructor_name: null
      +stock_available: true
      +stock: null
      +prices: array:4 [▶]

    }
    1 => Article {#347 ▼
      +user_id: null
      +article_id: 1885
      +family_id: null
      +active: true
      +creation_date: null
      +name: "CUENTO "AMIGOS/AS PARA SIEMPRE" LUXE"
      +description: null
      +detail: null
      +constructor_name: null
      +stock_available: true
      +stock: null
      +prices: array:4 [▶]

    }
```

I´m using the each method to filter:

```
$filtered = $api_items->each(function ($item, $key) {
    if($item != null) {
        return $item;
    }
});
```

But the $filtered return me again null values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assum that the both collections have always the same size, the solution will be something like :

```
$nested_result = [];

foreach($api_items as $index => $item){
     $item->name = $seo_items[$index]->name;
     $item->description = $seo_items[$index]->description;
     $item->detail = $seo_items[$index]->detail;

     $nested_result = $item;
}
```

Then use the **[`collect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-collect)** method to creates a collection instance from the `$nested_result` array :

```
$nested_collection = collect($nested_result);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is use code

```
$newArray = array();    
foreach($data as $key => $inner_array) {
    $ke = [];
    foreach($inner_array as $key_v => $inner_array_v){
        if($inner_array_v != 'N/A'){
          $ke[] = $inner_array_v; 
        }
    }
    $newArray[] =  $ke;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get rid of items from your array, try using the `filter()` function. I would also suggest trying using your truth statement inline and without $key/$value pairs

```
$filtered = $api_items->filter(function ($item) {
   return $item !== null;
});
```

By default the filter will look at the values and you end up with a more compact statement.